# how to disconnect client on a multithread chat

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, hashmap, chat

I want the client to disconnect when I enter the String "disconnect" but I don't understand how I could do it. Also, I need to remove the client from the hashMap so that it will be impossible for the client to send/receive messages.
I would appreciate any help I can get on it,been trying to find a solution for a while now but nothing seem to work.
here are the Client and server classes:

```
public class Clientt implements Runnable {//first we implement chat client

//the client socket        //sience we have multiple clients we are implementing threading in our application 
private static Socket clientSocket=null;
//the output stream
private static PrintStream os=null; //initializing the input & output streams
//the input stream
private static BufferedReader br=null;

private static BufferedReader inputLine=null;
private static boolean closed=false;
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    //the default port
    int portNumber=8080;
    //the default host
    String host="localhost";

    if(args.length<2)
    {
        System.out.println("Usage:Java Client <host> <portNumber>\n"
                +"now using host="+host+",portNumber="+portNumber);
    }
    else
    {
        host=args[0];
        portNumber=Integer.valueOf(args[1]).intValue();
    }

    /* 
     * Open a socket on a given host and port.
     * Open input and Output streams
     */

    try{
        clientSocket=new Socket(host,portNumber); //initializing clientsocket with mentioned host and port num
        inputLine=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));//read input from the user using inputLine
        os=new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());//outputstream is used to write to socket
        br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));// inputstream is uset to read from socket
    }catch(UnknownHostException e){
        System.err.println("Don't know about host"+host);
    }catch(IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for connection to the host"+host);
      }
    /*
     * If everything has been initialized then we want to write some date 
     * to the socket we have opened a connection to on the port portNumber
     */

    if(clientSocket!=null && os!=null && br!=null)
    {
        try{
            //Creat a thread to read from the server
            new Thread(new Clientt()).start(); //here we implement threading
            while(!closed)
            {
                os.println(inputLine.readLine());//loop continues infinetely untill we terminate application and writes to socket using output stream object
            }
            /*
             * Close the output stream,close the input stream,close the socket
             */
            os.close();
            br.close();
            clientSocket.close();
        }catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("IOException: "+e);

        }
    }

}

/*
 * Creat thread to read from the server
 * 
 */

//@Override

public void run() {
/*
 * Keep on reading from the socket of the server    
 */
 String responseLine; //used to implement reading from the socket
 try{
     while((responseLine=br.readLine())!=null){ //when we recieve messages we print out here
         System.out.println(responseLine); // "is" is the object of data input stream
     }
     closed=true;
 }catch(IOException e){
     System.out.println("IOException: "+e);
 }


}
```

}

```
public class Serverr implements Runnable {//server implements threading by implementing runnable interface
Socket csocket;
static HashMap<Integer,Socket>hm=new HashMap <Integer,Socket>(); //here we store each client socket in hashmap
static int k=1;
Serverr(Socket csocket){
    this.csocket=csocket;//Server ser=new Server(sock); comes here and assigns it to csocket
}

public static void main(String args[])
throws Exception{
    ServerSocket ssock=new ServerSocket(8080);//Socket on port 5000(same as mentioned inclient class)
    System.out.println("Listening");//when connected on port 5000 we print listening
    while(true){
        Socket sock=ssock.accept();//accept client socket
        Serverr ser=new Serverr(sock);//pass socket to constructor of server class
        new Thread(ser).start();//start thread here
        hm.put(k,sock);//add the socket into hashmap
        System.out.println("Connected to client"+k);//print the number of connected client
        PrintWriter out;
        for(int h=1;h<hm.size();h++)//loop through hashmap & get those socket value
        {
            Socket ser1=hm.get(h);

            out=new PrintWriter(ser1.getOutputStream(),true);//we will write to that socket here using outputstream
            out.print("Client "+k+" is connected");
            out.println();//we will get that specific message part 
            out.flush();
        }
        k++;
    }

}
{

}

@Override
public void run() {
    try{
        //once the thread is started we initialize necessary input & output streams here
        PrintWriter out;
        BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(csocket.getInputStream()));//used to read input from the socket
        String inputLine;
        String j="sending"; //follow a pattern for sending messages
        String l="to";
        String t="sendtoall";//used to sent message to all clients
        String lis="get_users";
        String clos="disconnect";
        while((inputLine=in.readLine())!=null)//if the message from connected client !=null
        {


            String a[]=inputLine.split(" ");//split the input line using space if a[0] is sendmsg and a[2] is to

             if(a[0].equals(j) && a[a.length - 2].equals(l))//we started the server
            {
                 int id=Integer.parseInt(a[a.length - 1]);//we will get the number of client here
                if(hm.containsKey(id)){// we will check hashmap if it contains id
                    Socket ser1=hm.get(id);//here we will get that clients socket from hashmap

                    out=new PrintWriter(ser1.getOutputStream(),true);// we will write to that socket using output stream
                    for (int word = 1; word < a.length - 2; word++ ) {
                        out.print(a[word]+" ");
                    }
                    out.println();//we will get that specific message part 
                    out.flush();// a[1] is...
                }
                else
                {
                    out=new PrintWriter(csocket.getOutputStream(),true);
                    out.println("user offline");//we print it if hashmap doesnt contain the key value
                    out.flush();
                }
            }
             else if(a[0].equals(lis))
                {
                    out=new PrintWriter(csocket.getOutputStream(),true);
                    for(int h=1;h<hm.size();h++)//loop through hashmap & get those socket value
                    {
                          out.print("Client number "+h+"is online");
                    }
                        out.println();//we will get that specific message part 
                        out.flush();
                    }

             else if(a[0].equals(t))//if we want to sent message to all clients at once
            {
                for(int h=1;h<hm.size();h++)//loop through hashmap & get those socket value
                {
                    Socket ser1=hm.get(h);

                    out=new PrintWriter(ser1.getOutputStream(),true);//we will write to that socket here using outputstream
                    for (int word = 1; word < a.length; word++ ) {
                        out.print(a[word]+" ");
                    }
                    out.println();//we will get that specific message part 
                    out.flush();
                }
            }

            else{
                out=new PrintWriter(csocket.getOutputStream(),true);
                out.println("Invalid Message");//if the message format doesnt match
                out.flush();
            }
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Close the socket, that'll definitely disconnect the client.

Comment: @Kayaman In that way I don't have worry about removing the client from the hashMap?

Comment: Sure you do. You don't want disconnected clients being there for no reason. Close the socket, remove the client from the map, you're done. It's not really that complicated, is it?